# Printer goes offline

Tags: network-printer

I have an HP LJ P2015 that is connected through a USB cable to a Trendnet TE100-P1U print server with the latest firmware installed.  We had a Windows 2000 server that was configured as a print server for this printer and all was well until we upgraded the server to Win 2003 Server.  Now the printer goes offline within about 30 seconds of restarting the print spooler.  We have several other printers on this server, none of which has a problem.  We've rebooted all machines and devices in the equation, but nothing works.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We ended up changing the ip address of the print server and that seems to have resolved this issue.  I'm not sure why this fixed it however, since there was no IP address conflict.

Answer (score 0):

When you upgraded the server, did you upgrade the printer drivers to a W2K3 version? If not, that would be my suggestion. If that fails, try uninstalling the printer, removing the driver, and then reinstalling the printer. If there's no W2K3 driver available, you can try a Windows XP driver.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but that has not helped...